# Каталога сайта CNcat: отдельная иконка для каждого поля

Tags: php

Стоит каталог сайтов - [CNCat](http://www.cn-software.com/ru/cncat/)
Я активировал 3 дополнительных поля при добавлении сайта в каталог (`ext_varchar1, ext_varchar2, ext_varchar3`) и хочу чтобы у каждой переменной была отдельная иконка т.е. `ext_varchar1-Вконтакте, ext_varchar2` - Твиттер, `ext_varchar3` - Facebook.
Я редактирую в шаблоне `extended.tpl` следующий код:

```
{IF $CNCAT[extfield][type] == 3}
    <tr>
       <td class="name">
          <img src="{$THEMEURL}images/VKONTAKTE.png" align="absmiddle">
          {cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][title])}:
       </td>
       <td class="text">
          <a href="http://{cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][value])}" target="_blank" title="{cn_str($CNCAT[item][item_title])}" rel="nofollow">
                  {cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][value])}
          </a>
       </td>
     </tr>
{ENDIF}
```

И если заполнены сразу три дополнительных поля (Вконтакте, твиттер, фейсбук), то иконка у всех трёх дополнительных полей выводится одна - Вконтакте, а как сделать чтобы у своей переменной выводилась своя иконка?

Спасибо!

Comment: что-нибудь типа
cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][icon]) ?

Comment: Не, я думаю как-нибудь через конструкцию If-else.
Например если заполнено ext_varchar1 (вконтакте), то выводить такую иконку, если заполнено ext_varchar2 (твиттер), то выводить иконку твиттера и так далее.
Просто я не знаю как это код (if-else) написать!

Answer (score 1):

```
{IF $CNCAT[extfield][type] == 1 && $CNCAT[extfield][title] != ''}
    <tr>
       <td class="name">
          <img src="{$THEMEURL}images/socialicon_{$CNCAT[extfield][type]}.png" align="absmiddle">
          {cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][title])}:
       </td>
       <td class="text">
          <a href="http://{cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][value])}" target="_blank" title="{cn_str($CNCAT[item][item_title])}" rel="nofollow">
                  {cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][value])}
          </a>
       </td>
     </tr>
{ENDIF}

{IF $CNCAT[extfield][type] == 2 && $CNCAT[extfield][title] != ''}
    <tr>
       <td class="name">
          <img src="{$THEMEURL}images/socialicon_{$CNCAT[extfield][type]}.png" align="absmiddle">
          {cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][title])}:
       </td>
       <td class="text">
          <a href="http://{cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][value])}" target="_blank" title="{cn_str($CNCAT[item][item_title])}" rel="nofollow">
                  {cn_str($CNCAT[extfield][value])}
          </a>
       </td>
     </tr>
{ENDIF}
```

Соответсвенно, нужно сделать файлы с другими именами - socialicon_1.png - вконтакте, socialicon_2.png - твиттер и т.д.